# How to check event object's state without actually changing it?

Tags: winapi

The problem is that the WaitForMultipleObjects(Ex) returns just smallest index of all the signalled objects in an array. I would like to know what exactly event objects (created using CreateEvent) are in signalled (or non-signalled) state.
I think it is not possible but decided to ask just to make sure I'm not missing anything =)

Answer (score 9):

For each object whose state you want to test, call `WaitForSingleObject` with a timeout of zero. If it returns `WAIT_OBJECT_0`, then the object is signaled. Otherwise, it's not.

Unless you have an auto-reset event, waiting for an object to become signaled does not alter its state.

Keep in mind that the state you detect with `WaitForSingleObject` isn't necessarily the same state the object had when `WaitForMultipleObjects` returned. More objects might have become signaled in the meantime, and other objects might have become non-signaled.

Comment: +1 Yup, seems the OP will have to loop through each object they care about, and check each one individually. (Also, as a FYI, while the OP is specifically asking about events here, be aware that WaitForSingleObject *does* change the signaled state of Mutexes and Semaphores, so care should be taken if any of the objects include those!)